# Terminating a do loop depending on an array variable that changes with the loop

Tags: javascript

I modified this code, which uses the euclidean algorithm, in order to generate an array of reminders.

It crashes (freezes/doesn't run). Thoughts?

```
var ne=prompt("Enter the first number n");
var me=prompt("Enter the second number m");
var n=ne;
var m=me;
var x=Math.floor(n/m);
var y=[] ;

y.push(n-m*x);
var i=1;
console.log(y[0] +"="+n+"-"+m+"*"+x);

do {
    n=m ;
    m=y ;
    x=Math.floor(n/m);
    y[i]=n-m*x ;
    console.log(y[i] +"="+n+"-"+m+"*"+x);
    var k=y[i];
    i=i+1;
} while (k!==0);

console.log(m+" is the greatest common divisor of "+ne +", "+ me);
y.toString();
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Freezes/won't run

Comment: Also, have a version that treats y as a normal variable and not an array (program prints out the steps of the algorithm and reads the gcd at the end) which was working but for some reason isn't now (was running, now returns infinite loop, zero change in code)?

I'm tossing this together on an online compiler I found for free, maybe that's what's going wrong?

Comment: No output? Are you prompted for the variables at the beginning?

Comment: Looks like an infinite loop, meaning k probably never === 0.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of exactly how to solve this yet, but I can tell you that you have an infinite loop within the do .. while block. The browser console spits out NaN NaN repeatedly, effectively freezing up the browser window / tab as you mentioned.

If you run Math.floor() with any alphas as parameters you'll get the NaN error, so the strict k !== 0 comparison will be true forever, hence the infinite loop.

do .. while's can be dangerous if you're not absolutely sure of the outcome / have done unit testing. I'd try evaluating the block:

```
n=m ;
m=y ;
x=Math.floor(n/m);
y[i]=n-m*x ;
console.log(y[i] +"="+n+"-"+m+"*"+x);
var k=y[i];
i=i+1;
```

once, without the loop first to see if you get more NaN's. Try a console log on x to see if it's spitting out NaN

```
x=Math.floor(n/m);
console.log(x, 'is x NaN?');
```

Update:

m=y, the second line in the do loop evaluates to [0]. So the next line, x is equal to Infinity. Also,

```
y.push(n-m*x)
```

(value of y) always seems to evaluate to [0], so you end up with m always = 0. in Math.floor(n/m).

What the console won't let you get far enough to see is the result of:

```
console.log(y[i] +"="+n+"-"+m+"*"+x);  // "NaN=2-0,NaN*Infinity"
```

then

```
var k=y[i];  // k is NaN
```